# Android value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONobject?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, illegalstateexception, gson

I am working with Json parsing with Gson. i know this question has been asked many times but i am not getting satisfactory solution.When i am parsing my response i am getting this error after showing the 2 items in list view 
**org.json.JSONException: Value no of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

here is my code,can anyone help me to solve my problem,that where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Here is my json response :-[response](http://pastie.org/10980224)

Here is my POGO class

**ProductResult.java**

```
 public class ProductResult {
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;
@SerializedName("count")
private String count;
@SerializedName("data")
private List<Product> product;


public String getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<Product> getData() {
    return product;
}

public void setData(List<Product> data) {
    this.product = data;
}
 }
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("product_id")
private String product_id;
@SerializedName("product_name")
private String product_name;
@SerializedName("product_discount")
private String product_discount;
@SerializedName("product_price")
private String product_price;
@SerializedName("product_img")
private String product_img;
@SerializedName("product_url")
private String product_url;
private String category_id;

@SerializedName("product_slug")
private String product_slug;
@SerializedName("product_base_image")
private String product_base_image;

private String size_chart;
private String product_addinfo;
private String product_style;
private String product_details;
private String product_care;
private String product_note;
private String product_material;
private String product_color;
private String product_offer;
private String product_offer_desc;
private String product_stock;
private ArrayList<String> product_thumbnails;
private ArrayList<String> product_images;
// private String product_size;
private String product_notify_text;
private String pincode;
private boolean product_returnable;
private String product_offer_title;
private String product_alert_message;
private ArrayList<String> product_size = new ArrayList<>();
private String product_count;

public Product() {

}


private ArrayList<ProductSizesEntity> product_sizes;
private ArrayList<ProductSizesEntity> product_notify_sizes;

private List<String> dimensions;


protected Product(Parcel in) {
    product_id = in.readString();
    category_id = in.readString();
    product_name = in.readString();
    product_discount = in.readString();
    product_price = in.readString();
    product_img = in.readString();
    size_chart = in.readString();
    product_addinfo = in.readString();
    product_style = in.readString();
    product_details = in.readString();
    product_care = in.readString();
    product_note = in.readString();
    product_material = in.readString();
    product_color = in.readString();
    product_offer = in.readString();
    product_offer_desc = in.readString();
    product_stock = in.readString();
    product_thumbnails = in.createStringArrayList();
    product_images = in.createStringArrayList();
    //product_size = in.readString();
    product_size = in.createStringArrayList();
    product_notify_text = in.readString();
    pincode = in.readString();
    product_returnable = in.readByte() != 0;
    product_offer_title = in.readString();
    product_alert_message = in.readString();
    product_count = in.readString();
    product_url = in.readString();

}


public static final Creator<Product> CREATOR = new Creator<Product>() {
    @Override
    public Product createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Product(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Product[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Product[size];
    }
};


public String getProduct_offer() {
    return product_offer;
}

public String getProduct_offer_desc() {
    return product_offer_desc;
}

public String getCategory_id() {
    return category_id;
}

public void setProduct_offer(String product_offer) {
    this.product_offer = product_offer;
}

public void setProduct_offer_desc(String product_offer_desc) {
    this.product_offer_desc = product_offer_desc;
}

public void setCategory_id(String category_id) {
    this.category_id = category_id;
}

public void setProduct_id(String product_id) {
    this.product_id = product_id;
}

public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
}

public void setProduct_discount(String product_discount) {
    this.product_discount = product_discount;
}

public void setProduct_price(String product_price) {
    this.product_price = product_price;
}

public void setProduct_img(String product_img) {
    this.product_img = product_img;
}

public void setSizeChart_img(String sizechart_img) {
    this.size_chart = sizechart_img;
}

public void setProduct_addinfo(String product_addinfo) {
    this.product_addinfo = product_addinfo;
}

public void setProduct_style(String product_style) {
    this.product_style = product_style;
}

public void setProduct_details(String product_details) {
    this.product_details = product_details;
}

public void setProduct_care(String product_care) {
    this.product_care = product_care;
}

public void setProduct_note(String product_note) {
    this.product_note = product_note;
}

public void setProduct_material(String product_material) {
    this.product_material = product_material;
}

public void setProduct_color(String product_color) {
    this.product_color = product_color;
}


public void setProduct_stock(String product_stock) {
    this.product_stock = product_stock;
}

public void setProduct_thumbnails(ArrayList<String> product_thumbnails) {
    this.product_thumbnails = product_thumbnails;
}

public void setProduct_images(ArrayList<String> product_images) {
    this.product_images = product_images;
}

public void setProduct_sizes(ArrayList<ProductSizesEntity> product_sizes) {
    this.product_sizes = product_sizes;
}

public void setProduct_notify_sizes(ArrayList<ProductSizesEntity> product_notify_sizes) {
    this.product_notify_sizes = product_notify_sizes;
}


public void setDimensions(List<String> dimensions) {
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}

public String getProduct_id() {
    return product_id;
}

public String getProduct_name() {
    return product_name;
}

public String getProduct_discount() {
    return product_discount;
}

public String getProduct_price() {
    return product_price;
}

public String getProduct_img() {
    return product_img;
}

public String getSizeChart_img() {
    return size_chart;
}

public String getProduct_addinfo() {
    return product_addinfo;
}

public String getProduct_style() {
    return product_style;
}

public String getProduct_details() {
    return product_details;
}

public String getProduct_care() {
    return product_care;
}

public String getProduct_note() {
    return product_note;
}

public String getProduct_material() {
    return product_material;
}

public String getProduct_color() {
    return product_color;
}

public String getProduct_stock() {
    return product_stock;
}

public ArrayList<String> getProduct_thumbnails() {
    return product_thumbnails;
}

public ArrayList<String> getProduct_images() {
    return product_images;
}

public ArrayList<ProductSizesEntity> getProduct_sizes() {
    return product_sizes;
}

public ArrayList<ProductSizesEntity> getProduct_notify_sizes() {
    return product_notify_sizes;
}

public List<String> getDimensions(List<String> dimensions) {
    return dimensions;
}

public String getProduct_url() {
    return product_url;

}
public String getProduct_base_image() {
    return product_base_image;
}

public void setProduct_base_image(String product_base_image) {
    this.product_base_image = product_base_image;
}


public void setProduct_url(String product_url) {
    this.product_url = product_url;
}

public String getDimensionAsString() {
    String strText = null;
    if (!(dimensions == null))
        strText = TextUtils.join(", ", dimensions);
    return strText;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(product_id);
    dest.writeString(category_id);
    dest.writeString(product_name);
    dest.writeString(product_discount);
    dest.writeString(product_price);
    dest.writeString(product_img);
    dest.writeString(size_chart);
    dest.writeString(product_addinfo);
    dest.writeString(product_style);
    dest.writeString(product_details);
    dest.writeString(product_care);

    dest.writeString(product_note);
    dest.writeString(product_material);
    dest.writeString(product_color);
    dest.writeString(product_offer);
    dest.writeString(product_offer_desc);
    dest.writeString(product_stock);
    dest.writeStringList(product_thumbnails);
    dest.writeStringList(product_images);
    //dest.writeString(product_size);
    dest.writeStringList(product_size);
    dest.writeString(product_notify_text);
    dest.writeString(pincode);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (product_returnable ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeString(product_offer_title);
    dest.writeString(product_alert_message);
    dest.writeString(product_count);
    dest.writeString(product_url);

}

public void setProduct_size(String product_size) {
    // this.product_size = product_size;
    this.product_size.add(product_size);
}

public ArrayList<String> getProduct_size() {
    return product_size;
}

public void setProduct_notify_text(String product_notify_text) {
    this.product_notify_text = product_notify_text;
}

public String getProduct_notify_text() {
    return product_notify_text;
}

public void setPincode(String pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

public String getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

public void setProduct_returnable(boolean product_returnable) {
    this.product_returnable = product_returnable;
}

public boolean isProduct_returnable() {
    return product_returnable;
}

public void setProduct_offer_title(String product_offer_title) {
    this.product_offer_title = product_offer_title;
}

public String getProduct_offer_title() {
    return product_offer_title;
}

public void setProduct_alert_message(String product_alert_message) {
    this.product_alert_message = product_alert_message;
}

public String getProduct_alert_message() {
    return product_alert_message;
}


public void setProduct_count(String product_count) {
    this.product_count = product_count;
}

public String getProduct_count() {
    return product_count;
}

public String getProduct_slug() {
    return product_slug;
}

public void setProduct_slug(String product_slug) {
    this.product_slug = product_slug;
}


public static class ProductSizesEntity {
    private String attr_id;
    private String quantity;
    private String attr_value;

    public void setAttr_id(String attr_id) {
        this.attr_id = attr_id;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setAttr_value(String attr_value) {
        this.attr_value = attr_value;
    }

    public String getAttr_id() {
        return attr_id;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getAttr_value() {
        return attr_value;
    }
}
}
```

Here i am using it like this

```
 ProductResult products  = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(),   ProductResult.class);
 mReceiver.onResponse(products, tag);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the "product" attribute in json response ?

Comment: Please check in your response link, which you posted as link. It doesnt have product attribute

Comment: @Vinodh yes yes..sorry   i updated it please check nowe

Comment: @Vinodh here is resposne : http://pastie.org/10980224

Comment: Easier way to create a POJO class http://json2csharp.com/# copy your response and generate .You will get the required POJO.

Comment: from where are u getting the **JSON** response and what's is the type of obj?

Comment: @UdayNaidu it is coming from server'

Comment: check what obj.toString() returns means check what is the response stored in object obj

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not an JsonArray into your json, it is a jsonobject. So you should use

```
@SerializedName("data")
private Product product;
```

instead of

```
@SerializedName("data")
private List<Product> product;
```

---

There are many issues into your second class. I am giving an [**online tool**](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), where you can create POJO class online. Here you need to put your Json string and click on zip. It will give you an option to download zip file with correct classes.

Comment: @pankaj...thanks for reply but i tried with product earlier in that case i got illegal argument exception

Comment: i check and let you know

Comment: @pankaj...i got this errror " Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 42 path $.data"

Comment: Check your json data. and what you used to create POJO.

Comment: i checked the link which you sent , it is same as my code